# Under what circumstances can the name portion of an eponymous invention be considered a word?

Tags: is-it-a-word, eponyms

I am aware of great debate over whether a name, in general, is a word in any language.  For purposes of this question, let's take the negative side of this debate.  For certain, I would never claim that my *nom de plume* of "cobaltduck" could be considered a word.  Nor do I claim that something like "Jason" or "Carl" is a word.

What about a name when applied to an eponymous invention?  There are many objects and ideas out there named after the inventor.  Let's consider just a couple examples:

1. The [Ferris wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferris_wheel), invented by American engineer George Washington Gale Ferris.
2. The [Diesel engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diesel_engine), invented by German engineer Rudolph Christian Karl Diesel.
3. The [Wankel engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wankel_engine), invented by German engineer Felix Heinrich Wankel.
4. The [Heimlich maneuver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdominal_thrusts), developed by American surgeon Henry Judah Heimlich.
5. And giving [credit where due](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/352089/13804)- inspired by a question by user Sadiq- the [Schottky diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky_diode), invented by German physicist Walter H. Schottky.

Can any of ferris, diesel, wankel, heimlich, or schottky be called a word?  If so, when and why?

I can see an argument for at least one definitely functioning stand-alone:

> Today in health class we learned how to do the heimlich.
>   Look!  Alice is choking.  Quick, somebody give her the heimlich.

And another is a maybe:

> I'm thinking of buying a pickup, and can't decide whether to get a diesel.
>   I need to fill this rig up with diesel. (referring to the fuel)

But another just doesn't work at all without the second part:

> Did you hear about Alice?  She went to the fair and got stuck on the ferris.

The others are also less certain, i.e. I don't know enough about the vernacular to know whether a motorcycle builder would ponder, "Should we put a wankel or a v-twin on this baby?" or one electrical technician would ask another, "Can you hand me that schottky over there?"

**To summarize:**  When, if ever, is the name portion of a name-object phrase describing something and its inventor, considered a word?

Comment: Perhaps your question makes a nonsense of the idea that a name is not a word?

Comment: That's really a  legal question. Of course, Ferris et al **are words**. They aren't sounds on a tape. They are proper nouns. It's just that they are part of a compound noun: Ferris wheel. A compound noun made up of a "proper"noun and a regular noun.

Comment: Your Ferris example isn't really a fair comparison. Obviously there are many motorists who might say *I can't decide whether to get a diesel* (though you won't be likely to hear *I can't decide whether to get a **petrol***). By the same token, a fairground operator discussing a future purchase might quite naturally say *I'm thinking about getting a Ferris if I can afford it*.

Comment: This is one of the reasons [Professor Crystal](http://www.davidcrystal.com/?id=3535) coined the term 'lexeme' for 'string comprising a unit of meaning', like these two: {run, runs, ran, running}; {kick the bucket} (when meaning 'die'). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiword_expression) prefers the term 'multiword expression (MWE)' for the latter type, including [open, at least,] compounds.

Comment: I've not come across the term 'part-proper noun' for say _Achilles tendon_ or  _plaster of Paris_ (which is also used without the capital nowadays), but perhaps it's necessary. // While the double capitalisations given in OP might be licensed somewhere, I've corrected them in line with the forms used in the accompanying references.

Comment: There is no agreement on terminology. For instance, [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/noun) has **noun**: A word (other than a pronoun) used to identify ... //  [but](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/steering_wheel): **steering wheel** NOUN 'A wheel that a driver rotates in order to steer ...'. Sadly, this is POB (and the situation needs rectifying).

Comment: The ontology of words is a vexed issue. Different people have different application conditions for the word "word". Generally, the name portion of a complex noun becomes a "word" (in some vague sense) when people begin to use it without knowing that it's based on a name.

Comment: A better question is when such names become *common nouns*. The answer is that they become common nouns when people begin to use them in syntactic positions reserved for common nouns.

Comment: @Silenus- your two comments seem like the beginnings of a fine answer.

Comment: There are even more layers of problems here: Hermione: "They only like him because he's famous! They wouldn't look twice at him if he couldn't do that Wonky-Faint thing." –
Harry: "Wronski Feint."
(Hermione Granger and Harry Potter discussing Viktor Krum in 'Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire', J K  Rowling.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've definitely heard people talk about 'a petrol' in the way you describe. Maybe not so much when talking about choosing a vehicle but certainly when discussing vehicles as in "Is that a petrol or a diesel?" Perhaps people don't say I'm thinking of getting a petrol" so much because a petrol engine is the default for cars.

Comment: @BoldBen: [In around two thirds of the (European Union) Member States for which detailed data are available, registrations of new passenger cars powered by diesel engines outnumbered new petrol powered cars.](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php/Passenger_cars_in_the_EU) It's usually called ***gas*** in AmE (and without looking it up I'm guessing diesels are less common in America anyway), but usage changes like this tend to appear *gradually*, in various isolated linguistic pockets, before possibly becoming mainstream/widespread.

Comment: Is this a question about English? It strikes me as more suitable for [linguistics.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ontology of words is a vexed issue in the philosophy of language.

We count different things as words in different contexts. Sometimes by "word" we mean something listed in the dictionary, other times we mean by "word" something uttered by a speaker.

Sometimes we count "color" and "colour" as the *same* word, but other times we don't. Sometimes we say that "bank" (qua riverside) and "bank" (qua financial institution) are two *different* words that just happen to share a phonic-graphic form. Other times we say that there is just *one* word, "bank", with different meanings. Sometimes an inscription of "legsltion" might count as the word "legislation", other times it might not.

Given the great variability in the application conditions of the word "word", it is best not to ask whether something is a word unless one has clearly identified one's criteria for wordhood.

---

I think a more interesting question is: When does the proper name portion of an eponymous invention name become a common noun?

The answer is—analytically—that names become common nouns when a significant number of speakers begin to use them in syntactic positions reserved for common nouns. This is not terribly informative, though, and the next question to ask is *why* speakers might begin to use names in common noun positions?

There are a few possibilities, but here are two:

First, speakers might start using [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) on expressions like "a Diesel engine" and "some Diesel fuel", rendering them "a Diesel" and "some Diesel," respectively. If enough people do this, for long enough, the word "Diesel" might just become a common noun.

Second, something like [deferred interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_reference) might be happening with the names. *Deferred interpretation* is the process whereby we use a word to refer to something which is related to what we'd normally use the word to refer to. For example, "Picasso" normally refers to the person Pablo Picasso. But we often use the word "Picasso" as a common noun to refer to works created by Pablo Picasso, as when we say "There are five Picassos in the Louvre." Something similar could be happening with "Diesel", "Heimlich," etc.

Maybe these two processes work together, maybe not. Maybe there is another explanation.

As to the question of why some names turn into common nouns (for example, "Diesel"), while others don't (for example, "Ferris"), there might be no definite 
reason. That said, maybe sociohistorical research would turn something up.

Comment: ISTM that a related question is “when can you use one component of a compound word to refer to the entire compound?”  For example, “peregrine” [is defined](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peregrine) as “having a tendency to wander”, but some consider it to be short for “peregrine falcon.”  But nobody would refer to a whooping crane as “a whooping”.

Answer (score 1):

To be definite, let's say something is an English word if it is listed in the current *Oxford English Dictionary*.  With that definition, these are words:

> Schottke, Diesel, Wankel, carl

and these are not:

> Ferris, Heimlich, Jason

But, on the other hand, *I* would say they are words the first time some speaker uses them, even if not listed in any dictionary.